# Nexus 4 / 7 and Wi-Fi incompatibility

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7, nexus-4

I have a Nexus 4 which works on most Wi-Fi networks, but not with my D-Link router running DD-WRT.  It connects, but data transfer is sporadic at best, and essentially useless.

Amongst the myriad of advanced settings in DD-WRT, there must be something that can get the Nexus 4 working?

(This question is also valid for the Nexus 7 as some users report similar problems).

Answer (score 1):

Updating dd-wrt to the latest build (15778 - D-Link 615 D2) fixed it for me.